# Using python to find points in a user designated polygon

Tags: python, csv, polygon

I'm trying to create a script in python to find out if points lay within or outside a polygon where the four corners are designated by the user, and then count how many fall into each category. So far my code looks like this, which I have adopted from the Ray Casting Method:

```
    import csv


    def point_in_polygon(x,y,poly):
    n = len(poly)
    inside = False

    point_x1,point_y1 = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        point_x2,point_y2 = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(point_y1,point_y2):
            if y <= max(point_y1,point_y2):
                if x <= max(point_x1,point_x2):
                    if point_y1 != point_y2:
                        xints = (y-point_y1)*(point_x2 - point_x1)/(point_y2-point_y1)+point_x1
                    if point_x1 == point_x2 or x <= xints:
                        inside = not inside
        point_x1,point_y1= point_x2,point_y2

    return inside

def a_reader():
    a_reader = open(r'datasmall.csv', 'rU')
    a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
    a_csv_reader.next()

    numRecords = sum(1 for line in open('datasmall.csv'))
    print (numRecords - 1, "<-- This is the number of stations")

    for row in a_csv_reader:
        return row

    a_reader.close()

a_reader()

## Input goes here. Will update all inputs after running properly

def main():

    x1 = input('What is X1?')
    y1 = input('What is Y1?')

    polygon = [(x1,y1),(10,10),(10,0),(0,0)]

    for row in a_reader:
        print point_in_polygon(float(row[1]), float(row[2]),polygon,)

main()
```

When broken down into stubs, all the separate parts work. My problem is when I'm trying to use my CSV file with a list of coordinates to see if they land inside the polygon and the values from the CSV file aren't being converted into floats. The error I receive is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "E:\spatial\Project\xy_input_list.py", line 16, in <module>
    import csv
  File "E:\spatial\Project\xy_input_list.py", line 62, in main
    for row in a_reader:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Now does this mean that in main() it isn't able pass the values from the CSV file to the point_in_polygon function?

The CSV file I've been using to practice is as such, as the one I'm hoping to use have many more values:

```
ID,Easting,Northing
1,10,10
2,1,2
3,5,5
4,6,3
5,4,0
6,4,9
7,0,0
```

I've managed to get the float method to work in other programs but I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing with ray casting that is making them clash somehow. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One other quick question as @jonrsharpe definitely helped and the program is running exactly as I was hoping it would: Before I was using `yield` and was using `return` in `a_reader` I could have a line saying `except IOError` if the file wasn't available to the program. Is there a different way I can write this to work with `yield`?

Comment: Figured it out :D thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to change

```
for row in a_reader:
...
```

to

```
for row in a_reader():
...
```

Comment: Welcome =)
btw, it was directly pointed at trace: `for row in a_reader:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: Sorry, I did reply before saying thanks, I don't know what happened. But thanks :) 

So if it is pointed at a trace, that means without the () and it can't run?

Comment: trace says, that `a_reader` is a function, so it is not iterable. Imo it's a pretty straight hint to try to call this func

Answer (score 0):

You need to *call* `a_reader` to get the `row` it returns:

```
for row in a_reader():
                 # ^ note parentheses
```

Also, that function can be improved - the `close` never explicitly runs, as it is *after* `return`, and you should `yield` each row rather than just `return`ing the first one:

```
def a_reader(filename="datasmall.csv"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        numRecords = sum(1 for line in f)
    print("{0} <-- This is the number of stations".format(numRecords-1))
    with open(filename) as reader:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(reader)
        csv_reader.next()
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield row
```

Comment: Okay so I've inserted that as is, but should it either be a_csv_reader at the top, or just a_reader at the bottom? Otherwise I get them being not defined globally.

Comment: @MattButton sorry, copy-and-paste-and-edit error. Fixed!

Comment: It worked!! Excellent :D :D Thank you so much :) Also is there a way I am able to tell how many stations returned true or false?

Comment: @MattButton of course, create `count = 0` then when you loop `for row in a_reader(): if point_in_polygon(...): count += 1`

Comment: Okay so I must be adding that in and be putting in the wrong place or...because now I don't get any True or False returns, only "This is the number of stations"

Comment: for row in a_reader():
        if point_in_polygon(float(row[1]), float(row[2]),polygon):          count += 1

Comment: @MattButton you aren't asking it to `print` the return value from `point_in_polygon`, so it doesn't; why are you surprised by this?

Comment: Oh sorry! What I was meaning was, am I able to print the True, False values as well as actually counting how many were returned as True and how many as False and display that too. Sorry, I didn't word it very correctly the first time.

Comment: @MattButton again, of course you can, but you will need to *tell Python that's what you want it to do*. Consider storing `result = point_in_polygon(...)` then using that for your various purposes.

Comment: Okay will get onto it :) Thank you very much you've been very helpful